# ¿Como unir 2 o mas xElement en c#?

Tags: c#, xml

Hola amigos resulta que quiero "Unir" 2 xElement iguales en estructura pero que cambias sus atributos, ya que estoy trabajando con cuestionarios moodle xml, necesito hacer lo siguiente

```
//Respuesta1
XElement Concatenar = new XElement("answer", new XAttribute("fraction", porcentajeRespuesta1),
            new XElement("text", new XCData(Respuesta1)));


//Pregunta2
XElement Concatenar = new XElement("answer", new XAttribute("fraction", porcentaRespuesta2),
            new XElement("text", new XCData(Respuesta2)));
```

Necesito que quede de la siguiente forma:

```
<answer fraction="100.000">
  <text>
    <![CDATA[Las especificaciones técnicas.]]>
  </text>
</answer>
<answer fraction="0">
  <text>
    <![CDATA[Lo que piensa el jefe de compras.]]>
  </text>
</answer>
```

Intente utilizar xElement.add() pero no funciono ya que quedaba asi:

```
<answer fraction="100.000">
  <text>
    <![CDATA[respuesta1]]>
  </text>
   <answer fraction="0">
      <text>
       <![CDATA[respuesta2]]>
      </text>
   </answer>
</answer>
```

la plantilla de xml que tengo de como deberia quedar es así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <quiz>
   <question type="category">
      <category>
         <text>__Category Name__</text>
      </category>
   </question>
<!-- Question entry 1 -->
   <question type="multichoice">
      <name>
         <text>
          <![CDATA[__Question 1]]>
         </text>
      </name>
      <questiontext format="html">
         <text>
          <![CDATA[Pregunta 1]]>
         </text>
      </questiontext>
      <answer fraction="100.000">
        <text>
          <![CDATA[Respuesta A]]>
       </text>
     </answer>
      <answer fraction="0">
       <text>
         <![CDATA[Respuesta B]>
      </text>
     </answer>
     <answer fraction="0">
      <text>
       <![CDATA[Respuesta C]]>
      </text>
    </answer>
    <answer fraction="0">
      <text>
       <![CDATA[Respuesta D]]>
     </text>
    </answer>
 <shuffleanswers>0</shuffleanswers>
 <single>true</single>
<answernumbering>abc</answernumbering>
 </question>
  </quiz>
```

pero como ven en mi fragmento de código, quedan unos dentro de otros y moodle no logra reconocer el formulario.
Discúlpenme, ya añadí la plantilla completa

Comment: Cual es el padre de <answer>?

Comment: Viene de una gran lista de nodos, la pondré en la pregunta

Comment: Deberías poner el xml completo

Comment: Corregido amigos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que salgan al mismo nivel deberán tener un padre, de lo contrario lo reconocera como un hijo.

```
//Respuesta1
        XElement Concatenar = new XElement("question",
                                new XElement("answer", 
                                    new XAttribute("fraction", "10"),
                                        new XElement("text", new XCData("Respuesta1")
                                        )),
                                     new XElement("answer",
                                         new XAttribute("fraction", "100"),
                                    new XElement("text", new XCData("Respuesta2")
                                    )
                                    ));
```

Output:

```
<question>
  <answer fraction="10">
    <text><![CDATA[Respuesta1]]></text>
  </answer>
  <answer fraction="100">
    <text><![CDATA[Respuesta2]]></text>
  </answer>
</question>
```